# Will creating a database using SQL Server Express 10 and using SQL Server Express 10.5 for running it cause any issue?

Tags: sql-server-express

If I create my database using SQL Server Express 10 and in target system where my application needs to run SQL Server Express 10.5, will I face any problems?

On my system I have SQL Server Express 10 installed (I guess it was installed with Visual Studio 2010) after sometime I installed VS2012 and removed it couple of months later. In my application I use `.\sqlexpress` in the connection string, I am not sure whether this is a SQL Server 2012 Express version or a 2010 version which is being used on my system?

So I just wanted to know if moving to the new system would cause me any kind of incompatibility or weird and unpredictable results and to avoid them what do I need to install on the target machine?

And also what would be sufficient to be installed on the target system by the way?

When I search SQL Server Express, there are several versions with different sizes, which one is needed and is enough?

Comment: SQL Server **2008** Express (v10) and SQL Server **2008 R2** Express (v10.5) are compatible - in an "upwards" manner. You can develop on the 2008 edition, and deploy to your customers on the **2008 R2** edition - but you **CANNOT** go back - e.g. you **cannot** back up a database on **2008 R2** at a customer site and then restore it locally into your **2008** instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is perfectly safe but you can't go back because the database will be upgraded.

Comment: what do you mean by that? will just connecting to a engine alter my database?And by the way will this upgrade affect localization of the database on sorting and comparison ?

Comment: Connecting does not alter anything - attaching a database does. It upgrades the database being attached. The database "localization" settings (called collation) will not be changed.